# Server is busy when open document

Tags: c#, ms-word, office-interop

I start a new application of word and open a document using Word-Interop. Sometimes this message pops up:

[image]

It seems to depend on how long it takes to open the document. Is there any possibility for setting a timeout?

```
Word.Application.oWord = new Word.Application();
Word.Document activeDocument = oWord.Documents.Open(fullName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem is caused by the Word FileDialog:

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.FileDialog fileDialog = oWord.FileDialog[Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoFileDialogType.msoFileDialogFilePicker];
fileDialog.Filters.Add("Word-Document", "*.docx");
fileDialog.Filters.Add("All Files", "*.*");
if (fileDialog.Show() == -1)
{
    if (fileDialog.SelectedItems.Count == 1)
    {
        fullName = fileDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1);
    }
}
```

When using the OpenFileDialog, then no error message "Server busy" pops up.

```
OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()
openFileDialog.Filter = "Word-Document (*.docx)|*.docx|All files (*.*)|*.*";

if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    fullName = openFileDialog.FileName;
}
```